# What are the indication or metrics of the data separation in the classification except the data visualization?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, computer-science, data-visualization, image-recognition

Besides the PCA or the representation of the data by projection it onto the two PCs and getting the plot in 2-D space, what are the other techniques that can give an indication of the data discrimination?

Answer (score 0):

When you have only two classes in your classification task you can use :

**1. ROC / AUC / GINI:** they might present you in a understandable manner whether the score from your classifier is good at separating your classes.

**2. ANN : VISUALIZATION OF A LAST LAYER:** you can use a some way of data visualization on outputs from a last layer of your network. If classes are well separated there - you may expect a good discrimination between them.

These are methods which I usually use. For multiclass task the second method stays the same. In the first you could use First vs Rest, Second vs Rest etc.

**UPDATE :** I strongly advice you to use other visualization / dimensionality reduction methods like **T-SNE** or **ISOMAPS**. You can read a detailed explaination of these methods [here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-10-Visualizing-MNIST/).